# Specifics of using NPM within Meteor

Tags: node.js, oauth, meteor, npm, yahoo-boss-api

I am trying to get OAuth working with Meteor.

I found an OAuth NPM, and now I'm trying to get it to be included in my Meteor project.

Here's what I'm trying:

I have a new folder next to the pre-made file called packages, and it's called "oauth".

Inside that folder, there is a single file called "package.js" and in there is:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Simple oauth"
});

Npm.depends({oauth: "0.9.10"});
```

And as part of the server-side code, it has:

```
Npm.require('oauth');
```

But I'm just getting an error of:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'oauth'
```

What, specifically, am I supposed to do?

This module doesn't have any dependencies, but I can't find any documentation on how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following the process explained here - https://coderwall.com/p/srvdta

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm` smart package. You have easy access 30k npm packages.

Read my [guide on how to do it](http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html).